# How to decide the padding size and stride size in CNN

Tags: cnn, pytorch

In CNN in 2d, what situation is the size of the padding and stride changed in?

So far, I could make sense of the basic concepts with padding and stride.

> Padding and stride can be used to adjust the dimensionality of the data effectively.
> https://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-neural-networks/padding-and-strides.html

On the one hand, the examples I had confirmed seemed to use `padding = 1` and `stride = 1`.

My question is

1. Using `padding = 1` and `stride = 1` is the basic and common method?
2. What situation do we adjust padding and stride size to over 1 in?

Answer (score 0):

Take a text classification as an example:

If you just look at one word at a time, you might not get the "meaning" of the word e.g the word `run`. But if you include two words at a time then you get the context e.g `didn't run` which is the oposite of `did run`.

Here we have `stride=2` since we stride/include 2 words at a time and not one.

When to use what padding/striding is defined by your data and model.